# Java | I need to make an applet but I don't know how to begin

Tags: java

I need to make kind of a game in Java but I am a total beginner. It has to be applicable to the web and I need to use images on it and action listeners. So, do you recommend any site to know how to begin?

The description of the game (it is not really a game but it implements things that usually are in a game) is this:

Show a matrix of images of 3x3 elements, then, hide them and put instead empty squares. The images shown in the matrix, must remain in the lower part of the screen just below the empty squares and they must be randomly positioned. The user, must click one image and put it on the correct empty square. The result, must be, how many images were correctly positioned, the time it took to end the game, the time between mouse clicked and released for each image.

For additional information, I want you to know that this application is for a friend of mine who studies medicine. He wants this program to test patients who accident and receive hits on their heads. You may think that the description I gave you may not be a good software for that purpose, and in fact, it may be not, but, once I know the management of all that is required (Images, MouseListeners, how to introduce it to a web etc), I will be able to make a better product. So, please tell me, how can I begin?. What do I need to know?

Comment: Start with learning Java, and then learn about Swing or/and Awt. You can also learn about JavaFx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html). Except for some startup boilerplate and the restrictions of the sandbax (which, based on your description, you will b unlikely to encounter), there is no fundamental difference in an applet from normal code.

Comment: Thanks! There is a lot of information there... But, according to the description I gave, wich objects would you use? for the images for example...
I have another question, http://java-elrincondetucasa.blogspot.com/2010/07/juego-concentrese_05.html, in this web, there is an applet, do all applets load like that one? this has nothing to do with the program I need, but, I only want to know if that loading "clock" appears in every applet?. Thanks for the link, I think it will be usefull.