# Can a Java made applet send information to the server?

Tags: java, applet

I want to know if an applet made in java, can send data to the server and store it on a data base. I'm trying to make something that is executed on the client side and gather information from the execution (sort of a game, i need time, correct and incorrect clicks). Is it better to do with JApplets or JavaScript?

For a description of what I need, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604836/java-i-need-to-make-an-applet-but-i-dont-know-how-to-begin)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your appet can communicate with the server which delivered the code for the applet.  If you need more than that,  you need to sign your code and ask for extra priviliges.

Comment: I just need to send Strings and int information to the server gathered from the execution in the client size. I imagine that it is totally possible, I need to read differences between javascript and java applets... How about learning java FX? what is the difference?

Comment: Javascript is an interpreted language embedded in the browser.  Java Applets is a window down to the Java Virtual Machine which runs your Java code.  Java FX is a different beast altogether - I would advise against spending time with it.  Have a look at the Applet section of the Java TUtorial by Sun.

Comment: There is also `crossdomain.xml`.

Comment: @Tom, please add a description to your link to make it useful to hardcopy readers.

Comment: @tom, or any other without internet access or who would like to hear in a few words what it is without having to start a research project.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this sort of thing a few years ago with rmi

a quick google found this: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/RMI/rmi/